# Remove White spaces from HTML output

Tags: magento-1.9, html, page

Our aim is to reduce page size. How can we remove White spaces from HTML output so page size can be reduced?

Remove inline css and javascript is one method to reduce page size which we have done already.

Comment: You can minify HTML, CSS and JS files to achieve this. For this you can use third party extensions for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below extension to get HTML, CSS and JS minify.

https://marketplace.magento.com/apptrian-apptrian-minify-html-css-js.html

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access you can install google pagespeed mod. This will automatically take all your worries of Compression, White spaces and Render blocking